# Changing the color of steps in the "cuisine" package

Tags: color

If you've used the `cuisine` package before, you will know that `\newstep` or `\ing` will lead to a step number being generated. In much the same way as the equation label in the equation environment, these steps are not directly modifiable. I was hoping that someone here might know how to change the colour (in this case, to the colour represented by "c59f61"). Any help would be hugely appreciated, as this is quite a difficult package to find documentation for!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=1.0cm,right=2cm,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25} % for custom spacing

\usepackage[nonumber]{cuisine}

% \RecipeWidths{Total recipe width}{Step number width}{Number of servings width}    {Ingredient width}{Quantity width}{Units width}
  \RecipeWidths{1\textwidth}{0.5cm}{3cm}{3.5cm}{0.75cm}{1cm}

\renewcommand*{\recipetitlefont}{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\recipequantityfont}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\recipeunitfont}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\recipeingredientfont}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand*{\recipefreeformfont}{\Large}

\begin{document}

\begin{recipe}{title}{servings}{time}

\ingredient[x]{unit}{ingredient}
\ingredient[x]{unit}{ingredient}

STEP 1 TEXT

\ingredient[x]{unit}{ingredient}

STEP 2 TEXT

\newstep

STEP 3 TEXT


\end{recipe}

\end{document}
```

What I would like to alter are the numbers which appear on the left handside which are not actually manually entered into the program, but rather appear as labels

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Jubobs Sorry about the lack of a MWE; I have now added one in (tested it locally and it compiles correctly).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package and its command `\color[model]{sepc}`, which is a switch like `\bfseries`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cuisine}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\recipestepnumberfont}{\color[HTML]{C59F61}}% must use uppercase letters

\begin{document}
\begin{recipe}{Yorkshire Pudding}{4 portions}{1\fr12 hours} 
    \ingredient[\fr12]{pt}{milk}
    \ingredient[2]{oz}{butter}
    \ingredient[5]{oz}{self-raising flour}
    Heat the milk and butter until nearly boiling. Add flour and allow to seeth over.
    \ingredient[3]{}{eggs}
    \ingredient{to taste}{salt and pepper}
    Add the remaining eggs and whisk again. Cook at 220\0C for about 1 hour.
\end{recipe}
\end{document}
```

If you need the same color at different places it is better to define a new one with

```
\definecolor{name}{model}{spec}
```

e.g.

```
\definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{C59F61}
```

which than can be used as `\color{mycolor}`

Comment: Better yet, `xcolor`

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! I hadn't realised that `\color` was a valid input/argument for `\renewcommand{\recipestepnumberfont}`

Comment: @egreg: Sorry, OSX stupid auto correction :-) the MWE is correct O:-)

Comment: @AYT: Your welcome :-)